# phpファイル間での関数内の実行結果の即時受渡し

Tags: php

どうかお教え願いませんでしょうか。以下のようにb.php内で計算された結果である変数$amountをa.phpへリアルタイムで渡したいのですがどうしてもできません。（a.phpとb.phpは異なる階層間にあります。）

この様な場合、何に問題があると考えられるのか、設定などをどのように変更すれば目的を達成できるか、あるいは全く異なる方法など、アドバイス、ご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

：追記

x.js

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"a.php",
data:"type=price",
success:function($amount){
$("#amount").val($amount);
}});
```

a.php

```
case 'price':   
require_once(PATH.'/b.php');
// 追記：$amount = "232321" 試しに左の様な設定にすると、問題が解決された結果になります。
echo $amount;

break;
```

b.php

```
追記：
// $amount = "237272"; 左記の様に値をfunction amount($db,$sum,$stay)の外に設定するとhtml上で237272が設定されますので、算出された実行結果である$amountの受け渡しは別として、php間、そしてjs、htmlでの値の受け渡しが確認されました。

function amount($db,$sum,$stay){
// 追記：global $amount; を試しましたが、$amountをa.phpで取得できていない様です。
//global $amount;

//諸々の計算
$sub_total1 = sum1 + $tax;
$sub_total2 = sum2 + $margin;
$amount =  $sub_total1 + $sub_total2;

// echo $amount;　この記述によって、$amountの値が上記の同じページの違う箇所に表示されます。   

//追記 html上の表示箇所。

if($type == 'html'){
//諸々のhtml上の設定。
$tem .= "<td>".number_format($sub_total1)."円</td>";
$tem .= "<td>".number_format($sub_total2)."円</td>";
$tem .= "<td>".number_format($amount)."円</td>";

return $tem  
} 

}
```

- システムフロー上はa.phpに$amountが渡った後、js、そしてhtmlに渡りそこで設定されますが、以上のa.phpで$amountがb.phpから渡っていれば私が抱える問題は解決されます。
- $_SESSIONも試しましたが、周回遅れ（前回）の計算結果が表示される様で、値の表示されるタイミングが合わないです。（リアルタイムに反映されない。）
- 以下の様な設定にすると、html上でb.phpの全記述が表示されますのでパス自体には問題がないと思われます。

a.php

```
case 'price':
$amount = file_get_contents(PATH.'/b.php');
echo $amount; 
break;
```

- 追記：
  a.phpを起動させる元のファイルは上記のx.jsです。data:"type=price",という形式でa.phpのcase 'price':を呼び、結果が得られれば#amountをhtmlに渡します。
- 追記：
  function amount()内での計算は全てこのfunction内で情報を取得し、計算されたものになります。かなり長い計算の為、ここでは混乱を回避する為に簡略化させて頂きましたが、必要とされる情報は提示していると思われます。
- 追記：
  b.php内のfunction amount($db,$sum,$stay)内の実行結果である$amountをグローバル変数にする方法が分かりません。あるいは、上記にも記しましたが、この実行結果である$amountを算出直後にfunction amount($db,$sum,$stay)の”外”に設定できれば、php,php,js,htmlと値が受け渡せると思われます。

-最新-

- 追記：
  最初に情報提供できなく申し訳ございません。function amount内にhtml表示をする箇所がありreturn値はそのhtmlに返されます。このhtml用の戻り値（return $tem）を削除し、return $amountにすると、php,php,js,htmlと$amoutnが渡り、当初の目的が実現されますが、そのhtmlは削除できません。よって、return $amountを使用できないと思われますが、本件の様なhtmlを使用している場合、複数の戻り値を返す様なことはできるのでしょうか。
- 追記：
  Classを使用すると、システムの他の記述が影響を受ける様でかなり大掛かりに変更をかけない限り機能しませんので、現時点では保留にした方が良さそうです。
- 追記：
  グローバル変数がリスクが皆無で、本システムでも機能しているのであれば、一番簡単に実装できそうなのですが、現時点で機能させることができていない以上、同じことになるかもしれませんが、function amount2の様な新たな$amount用のための関数を作成し、そこでfunction amountの$amountを取得し、a.phpへ渡すなどっといった方法はありませんでしょうか。

Comment: `require_once`しているのを見落としていました。読み込まれているので`amount`を普通の関数と同じように扱えばいいかと思います。この関数内で使用されている`sub_total1`などはどこから来たのでしょうか？グローバル変数であれば`global`で明示的に指定する必要があるかと思います。

Comment: echo file_get_contents('http://yyzxx.jp/b.php'); のように　URLの指定が許される環境なら、file_get_contentsでも実行結果を得る事が出来ると思います。

Comment: Sieg様、ご教授感謝いたします。sub_total1などはb.php内のfunction amount()内で全て取得、計算されたもになります。その実行結果である$amountをa.phpで取得したいだけですが、global $amount;の様にしても未だ、a.php内で取得できておりません。通常であれば、他phpファイルの変数はrequire_onceでパスを指定して、変数自体をもう一方のphpファイルで指定すれば取得できますよね？

Comment: もしかすると質問欄外で記載あるかもしれませんが、`amount(??,??,??);`のように`a.php`で実行されていますか？関数宣言で引数を要求しているので引数が必要かと思います。また、現状の記述でいう`a.php`がグローバルなので、`b.php`の`function`内のスコープで参照する変数に`global`を入れる認識はあっておりますか？もし、`b.php`を読み込むだけで実行したいなら、`function`の中から記述を外に出す必要がありますが、その認識はあっておりますか？

Comment: Sieg様、ご教授大変感謝致します。上記の追記で記しましたが、実行結果である$amountを算出後にfunction amount($db,$sum,$stay)の外に設定する方法はありますでしょうか。function amount($db,$sum,$stay)内でグローバル変数に設定しfunction amount外で読み込み可能にすることを試しましたが、システムがハングアウトしてしまいます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

案１：戻り値を使う
a.php

```
//Require
require_once(PATH.'/b.php');
//実行
$amount = amount($db,$sum,$stay);
//出力
echo $amount;
```

b.php

```
function amount($db,$sum,$stay){
    //諸々計算
    $sub_total1 = sum1 + $tax;
    $sub_total2 = sum2 + $margin;
    //計算結果をなんか変数に代入
    $res =  $sub_total1 + $sub_total2;
    //値を返却
    return $res;
}
```

---

案２：グローバル変数に保存する（非推奨）
a.php

```
//Require
require_once(PATH.'/b.php');
//念のためグローバル変数初期化
$amount = '';
//実行
amount($db,$sum,$stay);
//出力
echo $amount;
```

b.php

```
function amount($db,$sum,$stay){
    global $amount;
    //諸々計算
    $sub_total1 = sum1 + $tax;
    $sub_total2 = sum2 + $margin;
    //計算結果をなんか変数に代入
    $amount =  $sub_total1 + $sub_total2;
}
```

---

特に理由もなくグローバル変数を汚すことはオススメしません。
可能であれば処理スコープ内で変数をクローズするべきかと思います。

---

**追記**

案3：Classを使う
a.php

```
//Require
require_once(PATH.'/b.php');
//class初期化
$smp = new Sample();
//実行
$smp->amount($db,$sum,$stay);
//出力
echo $smp->val;
```

b.php

```
Class Sample{
    public $val = '';

    public function amount($db,$sum,$stay){
        //諸々計算
        $sub_total1 = sum1 + $tax;
        $sub_total2 = sum2 + $margin;
        //計算結果をなんか変数に代入
        $this->val =  $sub_total1 + $sub_total2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sieg様、ご教授頂きまして本当に感謝いたします。一つ質問させて頂きたいのですが、戻り値、グローバル変数以外で、本ケースの様な他PHPファイルの関数内の変数を取得する場合、アロー関数などを利用して直接$amountを取得するような方法はないのでしょうか。

Comment: @baseballjapan Classを使うのがいいかと思います。ちゃんと説明すると一言では説明できないので、Classについては別質問がよろしいかと思います。

Comment: @baseballjapan Classを使ったサンプルも記載しておきました

Comment: Sieg様、ご多忙の中度々恐縮でございます。まず上記に追記を致しました。そしてPHPの様々な手法等をお教え頂きまして本当に感謝致します。お教え頂いた手法の中から、returnが機能していることが分かりました。システム的にhtmlで$amountを取得できました。ただし、追記にも記しました様に
現状では普通の方法では使用できないと思われます。他にも色々と試しておりますが、何か本件の様な特殊なケースで機能しそうな手法、アイデアなどありましたらお教え願いませんでしょうか。

Comment: @baseballjapan えーっと追記読みましたが、まず回答により追記が出たり、コメントにて延々とQAが繰り返されるような質問はSO的には十分に纏められてない質問＋他多数の閲覧者に有益ではない。として敬遠される傾向にあります。主題の別ファイルの関数から値を受け渡しする方法としては完結してると思うので一度質問を承認するなどして閉じて、新しい質問を立てた方がいいと思います。このままでは回答した時点と今とで質問が変わっているので今の回答が意味をなさなくなってしまいます。

Comment: @baseballjapan とりあえず、追記に対してのみコメントで返しておきます。
何にせよ、コード全文が分からない現状ズルズル行きそうな気はしますが……
`1.複数の戻り値`：配列を作成してそれを返却しては？、
`2.リスクが皆無〜、関数を作成し〜渡す`：まず仕様をしりコードレビューしないとリスクはわからないかと、外部ファイルでHTML(クライアント側へ出力)するのもどうかと思いますが、関数内で無名関数を返却し、その別関数で処理するのも一つの手かな？と思いました。

Comment: Sieg様、長々と大変申し訳ございません。ご多忙の中、様々なことをご教授頂きまして感謝の限りでございます。本当にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

まず原因ですが、require_onceはあくまで別のファイルを読み込んでいるのであって、実行しているわけではありません。

case文の中でb.phpを読み込んではいますが、ソース上は

```
case 'price':
  function amount($db,$sum,$stay){
    $amount =  $sub_total1+$sub_total2;
  }
  echo $amount;
  break;
```

となっているだけでfunction amountは呼ばれておらず、無視されている状態となっています。

現状の情報ではアドバイスが難しいので、もう少しソースコードを見せることは可能ですか？

Comment: require_onceは読み込みして実行するような。”include(require) 文は指定されたファイルを読み込み、評価します。”と説明があります。　http://php.net/manual/ja/function.include.php

Comment: 少し説明ミスですね...。実行しないというよりは、現状のソースだとfunctionの宣言だけしているので実行されないが正しいですかね？ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: yyz様、ご教授大変感謝いたします。include、あるいはrequireでもためしましたが、$amountをa.phpで取得できないようでございます。

Comment: media_yama様、ご教授大変感謝いたします。計算自体はb.php内のfunction amount()内で全て、情報を取得、算出されます。ご教授いただきました様にa.php内のcase文の中でfunction amountを使用し試しましたが、未だ取得できないようでございます。本ケースの様なphp間の値の即時受け渡しはパスを指定して変数を設定するだけではだめなのでしょうか？いろいろと試しておりますが、やはり、a.phpで変数を取得できないのが原因であると現時点では考えております。

Comment: media_yama様、情報提供不足、そして混乱させてしまい申し訳ございません。a.phpのcase 'price':はjavascriptのajaxでdata:"type=price",として呼んでおりますが、その段階でfunction amountを起動させなければ、$amountを取得できないということでしょうか。

Comment: @media_yama さん、説明の間違いがあれば回答下の「編集」から随時書き直せますのでお試しください<(_ _)>　回答の意味を変えない程度であれば、どんどん良い回答にアップデートしていくための機能です。